# Laravel Get property with many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

my user model:

```
public function roles()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role_pivot', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

my role model:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_role_pivot', 'role_id', 'user_id');
}

public function rolepermissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_permissions_connect', 'role_id', 'role_perm_id');
}
```

In laravel i want to get request user role permissions, this is my relation in tables. How can i get property of role_permissions?
i tried this one:

```
$user->roles->rolepermissions->pluck('permission_name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Role` model your `rolepermissions` are linked to `App\User` model:

```
public function rolepermissions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'role_permissions_connect', 'role_id', 'role_perm_id');
}
```

You should change `belongsToMany('App\User' ...` to `belongsToMany('App\RolePermission'` probalby.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user=User::find(1);    
foreach($user->roles as $role)
    {
       foreach($role->rolepermissions as $rolepermission)
       {
             echo $rolepermission->permission_name;
       }
    }
```